# Why cant there be classes inside methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can I create Ruby classes within functions bodies ?
I seem to be getting error which tells me its not allowed but I think it should be as classes are too objects here.

```
class A
    def method
        class B
        end
    end
end
```

This fails with error 'class definition inside method body.
If we cant, why cant we create classes inside methods ?

Comment: why would you ever want to do this?

Comment: @Mark - I do this all the time with anonymous objects in C#.  Granted, they don't have methods per se, but it's still a valid reason to want to create a class on the fly.  A short-lived container object to hold some data temporarily that I can use in a strongly-typed manner (at least referencing properties by name) is a really handy thing to have around.

Comment: @Mark- exactly as tvanfosson said !

Comment: It'd also be useful to conditionally monkey-patch a class.

Comment: @MarkElliot In testing, for instance. Besides, some core dev created this error condition for a reason, it probably was allowed until someone made it expressly forbidden.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class A
  def method
    self.class.const_set :B, Class.new {
      def foo
        'bar'
      end
    }
  end
end

A.new.method
A::B.new.foo # => 'bar'
```

However, why do you want to assign a constant inside a method? That doesn't make sense: constants are *constant*, you can only assign to them once which means you can only run your method once. Then, why do you write a method at all, if it is only ever going to be run once, anyway?

Comment: I can think of several patterns that might conceivably define classes in a method, most notably things like bridges, adapters, and factories. It would be useful if you need to get some static resource (like an LDAP connection), but you don't want to dictate the implementation (e.g. net/ldap vs ruby-net-ldap). Still, it's far from an everyday need.

Comment: I want class to be local to action instance. So that the class instances are doomed to be garbage collected once the action is finished. Namely, I do soap request, parse it as instances of some class (so that they reply to some calls). And pass `@things` to the view. Once the view is rendered, I don't want to remember `@things` at all.

Answer (score 12):

you can create classes, but you cannot assign constants from inside a method.

this example works:

```
class A
  def a
    b = Class.new
    def b.xxx
      "XXX"
    end
    b
  end
end

a = A.new.a
p a         # #<Class:0x7fa74fe6cc58>
p a.xxx     # "XXX"
```

Comment: This is a better answer. OP wanted to know **why**. You've explained why.

Comment: His question was about defining a class inside a method, not instantiating one. This answer does not address the question.

Answer (score 10):

You can create classes from within methods and assign them to a constant, as in the following

```
class A
  def create_class class_name
    new_class = Class.new
    new_class.send :define_method, :speak do
      "Hi, There"
    end
    Object.const_set class_name, new_class
  end
end

A.new.create_class "Harry"
h = Harry.new
puts h.speak  # responds => "Hi, There"
```

because a class name as in String is just a constant in ruby unlike many other languages.

Answer (score 4):

The question is about creating classes, but in the comment you talk about creating anonymous *objects*. Not the same thing.

If you need anonymous object, you can always do `Object.new`. If you need simple struct-like container, you should take a look at [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Struct.html) class. With it, you can do something like:

```
def foo
  anon_obj = Struct.new(:prop1, :prop2).new
  anon_obj.prop1 = 123
  anon_obj.prop2 = 'bar'

  return anon_obj
end
```

BTW, Ruby *is* a strongly typed language. But it is a dynamic typed as well, and you can't expect it to behave like static-typed.