# How to parametrize a class in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying to port this pattern to parametrize a class from Python to Ruby: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/blob/6a8d85e5f64935b6c2a409291e9f6578a7bfe1b0/prometheus_client/core.py#L395-L434

The outer method sets some variables and then internally defines a class which closes over these values. The result is that all objects created from this returned class share some common state.

I can't do this in Ruby because Ruby doesn't allow class definitions in methods:

```
def foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

This yields the error: `class definition in method body`.

What's the right way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: “Ruby doesn't allow class definitions in methods”—why is that? Perfectly allows.

Comment: Trying to define a class in a method gives me the following error: "class definition in method body".

Comment: Excuse me, have you ever read the rules of this site? Please post the code you were trying to run, post the error message you have received and I will be able to show what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dynamically create a class in Ruby, you can. You cannot define a constant inside a method though, at least not in the usual way. See [those](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194321/6419007) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426510/6419007) for more information.

```
def create_class(methods = {})
  klass = Class.new
  methods.each do |method_name, value|
    klass.send(:define_method, method_name) do
      value
    end
  end
  klass
end

my_class = create_class a: 'Hello', b: 'World'
my_instance = my_class.new
puts my_instance.a
#=> "Hello"
puts my_instance.b
#=> "World"
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that there would be maybe a less kludy pattern to achieve the same in Ruby, but this should work!